# return BOOL Type

Tags: iphone

I want to make checkindatabase with return type `BOOL` and return `TRUE` if Login successful and `FALSE` otherwise. For a login page , but some how it is coming error to me, can any one help me out and post the exact code for this.

```
-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender

{

[self checkindatabase];

}
```

Comment: Neither you are showing your code nor any direction to the same if its webserver or local data. How can anybody help you? More explanation would result you in good and quick replies.

Comment: @makumar I think you need to take a step back and get a firm understanding of the basics of programming rather than reposting other people's answers to your questions and asking for people to write the code for you.  That is not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this, if it doesn't work then you need to give more info on the error you are getting...

```
-(BOOL) checkindatabase {
    // do some stuff
    return TRUE; // (or FALSE ...)
}

-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender
{
    BOOL result = [self checkindatabase];

    if (result) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something else 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if your BOOL value is true or false you could do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)homePage:(id)sender {
    if([self checkInDatabase]) {
        NSLog(@"True");    
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not true");
    }
}
```

By the way, I would strongly recommend that you read this [article](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html).

Comment: My condition should be like if ([self checkINDatabase]=True){}else{}but doing this is showing error to me': Statement requires expression of scalar type

Answer (score 0):

Putting your comment into consideration,it should be `if (checkINDatabase==True){}else{}`

Answer (score 0):

1) This question is terrible - no real code, no description of the error etc.

2) Reading the answers and their comments it looks like you have written

```
if ([self checkINDatabase] = True) {
} else { 
}
```

With the error `Statement requires expression of scalar type`.

Try this :

```
if ([self checkINDatabase] == True) {
```

(note the double equals!).

and make sure that your checkINDatabase method is defined as

```
- (BOOL)checkINDatabase {
```

and not

```
- (void)checkINDatabase {
```

Also, do you have any other warnings when you compile?